# How to run notebook from jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am working on setting up jupyter lab in Kubernetes. I have followed [document](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/jupyterhub/index.html)  to setup it.

I have successfully launched the jupyterhub and it server spawn is also working. But when launching jupyter notebook and selecting the kernel it says

```
**Error Starting Kernel Invalid response: 503 Service Unavailable**
```

How to resolve this?

How to successfully launch the Kernel in jupyterlab when setup is on kubernetes?